# Cypress page objects model - use data-test-id or use React test Library cy.findByText to find page object elements?

Tags: cypress, react-testing-library, pageobjects

I am creating a page object for a webpage for a web app that I am testing.  I am using Cypress for my automated tests.

I was thinking about using one of two methods for finding page elements. See my options below:-

**Option 1 - get the developers to add data-test-ids to page elements. See example:-****

```
elements = {
    homePageNavLink: () => cy.get('[data-test-id="home-page"]')
}

clickHomePageLink(vehicleNum) {
     this.elements.homePageNavLink().click();
}
```

**Option 2 - Use the React testing library - @testing-library/cypress. See example:-****

```
elements = {
    vehicleNumberInput: () => cy.findByText('home')
}

clickHomePageLink(vehicleNum) {
     this.elements.homePageNavLink().click();
}
```

Are there any benefits of choosing one way over the other?

Answer (score 1):

According to Cypress best practices you should use `data-` attributes for e2e testing.

`findByText()` method is commonly used for unit testing. If you want to select an element by text with Cypress you can use `cy.contains()`.

Source: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices

Answer (score 0):

I did some experimentation I came to the conclusion that if you use the **findByText()** method and there are two elements on the page with the same text, then Cypress falls over. So its best to use the **'data-testid'** if it has been provided